# Sorting product list New added products and matching name products should be grouped

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1

I want to Sort product listing by new added product, and I did it by adding code

```
 $this->_productCollection->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc')
```

It is working fine, Now I want to show products as a group those has matching name 
like, TOP-blue, TOP- green, TOP- red

Is it possible ? any help appreciable

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer is to create a product attribute, that allows to be used with layered navigation. That way, when you sort, on the left hand side, it will say something like:

"Group"

- Top Blue
- Top Green
- Top Red

etc.

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 3]

Remember that is has to be either a dropdown or multiselect, you must select it to be used in layered navigation, assign it to a attribute group, and the category must be a anchor.

Also, by doing this as an product attribute, you could even have them sort on the category page by groups.